# Create shortcode to insert CTA button with with javascript event tracking

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I want shortcode to insert a CTA button that says "Request a Quote", but also want it to include onClick event tracking code with the current page title.

This code breaks WordPress (I think it's a problem with single and double quotes)

```
function my_cta() {
    $title = echo get_the_title();
    return '<div class="mycalltoaction"><a class="button" href="/contact-us/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'QuoteRequest', 'Click', '$title']);">Request a Quote <strong>TODAY</strong></a></div>';
}
add_shortcode('cta', 'my_cta');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You got syntax error on some of your code. I already got it fixed.

```
<?php
function my_cta() {
    return `<div class="mycalltoaction"><a class="button" href="/contact-us/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'QuoteRequest', 'Click', '`.get_the_title().`']);">Request a Quote <strong>TODAY</strong></a></div>`;
}
add_shortcode('cta', 'my_cta');
```

1. is on the **$title = echo get_the_title();** you should not assign echo to a variable.
2. you combined string with the variable without closing the string. **(['_trackEvent', 'QuoteRequest', 'Click', '$title']);**

Comment: Are those back ticks surrounding    .get_the_title().   and the whole return statement?

Comment: It isn't working. When I add the shortcode on page [cta] nothing happens on front end. I don't see the shortcode and nothing is added to the HTML. It just seems to be ignored.

Comment: If I remove the function, then the [cta] displays as text on front end.